# How can I create a dynamic list of Input field which create another input field when you write and delete it when the input is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm new to jQuery and in my current project I need to create a list of inputs with following conditions:

- When I write something in the first input field another input fields spawns
- When I delete the chars and the input field is empty, it will be deleted
- In the end all the values will be combined into one string
- If possible the list should be in an array (optional)

I'm limited because my knowledge of jQuery isn't good. I managed to create the first condition but I don't know if my solution is any good.

http://jsfiddle.net/kubydpvr/5/

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let count = 0;
  let arr = [createInput(0)];
  $(".Fields").append(arr);

  function addListField() {
    $("#id_" + count).one("input", addListField);
    $("#id_" + count).attr({
      type: "text"
    });
    arr.push(createInput(count + 1, "hidden"));
    $("#id_" + count).after(createInput(count + 1, "hidden"));
    count++;
  }

  function createInput(id, type = "text") {
    return (
      "<input type=" + type + ' value = "" id = id_' + id + " ></input>"
    );
  }
  addListField();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background: whitesmoke;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

header {
  background: rgb(1, 60, 14);
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px rgb(26, 0, 62) solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.Fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>I Learn jQuery.</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="Fields"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your after

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let count = 0;
  let arr = [createInput(0)];
  $(".Fields").append(arr);

  function addListField() {
    $("#id_" + count).one("input", addListField);
    $("#id_" + count).on("change", function() {
      let item = parseInt($(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]);
      if (!$(this).val().length) {
        arr.splice(item, 1)
        $(this).remove();
      }
    })
    $("#id_" + count).attr({
      type: "text"
    });
    arr.push(createInput(count + 1, "hidden"));
    $("#id_" + count).after(createInput(count + 1, "hidden"));
    count++;
  }
  $("#output").on("click", function() {
    let vals = [];
    $('[id^=id_]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        vals.push($(this).val())
      }
      //vals += $(this).val()
    })
    console.log(vals)
    console.log(arr)
  })

  function createInput(id, type = "text") {
    return (
      "<input type=" + type + ' value = "" id = id_' + id + " ></input>"
    );
  }

  addListField();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  background: whitesmoke;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

header {
  background: rgb(1, 60, 14);
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px rgb(26, 0, 62) solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.Fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learn jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>I Learn jQuery.</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="Fields"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="output">
        Output
      </button>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps